# tf.train.shuffle_batch hangs forever (using tensorflow ver. 1.4)

Tags: tensorflow, queue

I've a small tfrecords file with only 640 records. Below code hangs and I don't know what's wrong with it:

```
def read_from_tfrecord(tfrecord_file):
   tfrecord_file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tfrecord_file, name = 'queue')
   reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
   _, tfrecord_serialized = reader.read(tfrecord_file_queue)    
   tfrecord_features = tf.parse_single_example(tfrecord_serialized,
   features = {'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),                
               'snippet': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}, name = 'features')

   snippet = tf.decode_raw(tfrecord_features['snippet'], tf.float32)
   snippet = tf.reshape(snippet, [x_height, x_width, num_channels])
   label = tf.decode_raw(tfrecord_features['label'], tf.int32)
   label = tf.reshape(label, [2])

   snippets_shuffled, labels_shuffled = tf.train.shuffle_batch([snippet, label], 
                                                                batch_size = 2, 
                                                                capacity = 10, 
                                                                num_threads = 1, 
                                                             min_after_dequeue = 4)
    return snippets_shuffled, labels_shuffled
```

and:

```
with tf.Session()  as sess:    
   coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
   threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

   snippet, label = read_from_tfrecord(['./TFRecordFile/test_tmp.tfrecords'])
   print('1') # it prints 1
   a, b = sess.run([snippet, label]) # it hangs here!
   print('2') # it never prints 2
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: try to put `snippet, label = read_from_tfrecord(['./TFRecordFile/test_tmp.tfrecords'])` before `tf.Session()`. it might help.

Comment: @Seven I tried your suggestion. Now, I'm getting this error: `OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)
  [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]`

Comment: It seems it has nothing to do with `snippets_shuffled, labels_shuffled = tf.train.shuffle_batch(...)`. When I comment it out and return `return snippet, label` instead, I still get the same problem! –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved the issue. I spent a lot of time to make this working. So, I post the answer here in case others face a similar problem. On top of what Seven suggested,

I had to add `tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)`. The code will look like this:

```
snippet, label = read_from_tfrecord(['./TFRecordFile/test_tmp.tfrecords'])    
with tf.Session()  as sess:    
       coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
       threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
       tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess) # <==== Add This Line
       sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

       print('1') # it prints 1
       a, b = sess.run([snippet, label]) # it hangs here!
       print('2') # it never prints 2
```